# How do I transfer the results of a computation from a notebook into a Mathematica.SE question?

Tags: discussion, formatting

i have establish the ODE model and in order to simplify the question,I just want to put the ODE, but when I get the ODE from mma, how can I paste it to mse?

codes are as this

```
G = m*g;
d1 = (m)/(rho*area);
omega = 2*\[Pi]/T0;

y[t_] = h/2*Cos[omega*t];
f = rho*g*area*(y[t] - x[t]) + (m)*g;(**)
vr = y'[t] - x'[t];
ar = y''[t] - x''[t];
drag = 1/2*rho*cd*area*vr*Abs[vr];
ca[x_] = Piecewise[{{ca1, x'[t] >= 0}, {ca2, x'[t] < 0}}];
interiaforce = 
  rho*area*(d1 - x[t] + y[t])*(y''[t]) + 
   ca[x]*rho*area*(d1 - x[t] + y[t])*ar;

a = D[x[t], {t, 2}];

t1up = (a j3)/r3^2 + (a j4)/r4^2 + 
   1/2 (2 (a m1 + g m1) + (2 a j1)/r1^2 + (2 a j2)/r1^2 + (
  2 a j5 r2^2)/(r1^2 r5^2) + (2 a j6 r2^2)/(r1^2 r6^2) + (
  2 a j7 r2^2)/(r1^2 r7 (r6 + r7)) + (2 g m2 r2 r7)/(
  r1 (r6 + r7)) + (a m2 r2^2 r7)/(r1^2 (r6 + r7)));

t1down = ((a j1)/r1 + (a m1 + g m1) r1)/r1 + (a j3)/r3^2 + (a j4)/r4^2;

tension1 = Piecewise[{{t1up, x'[t] >= 0}, {t1down, x'[t] < 0}}];

equa00 = f + drag + interiaforce - m*g - tension1 == m*a
```

how can I put the calculation result of `equa00` on mse but when I put it,the result is Random code.

Comment: will this form be calculated?

Comment: Of course. Just try it out if you don't believe. (So, you didn't read the tutorial [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/209136/how-to-output-results-in-a-specific-format#comment536596_209136), right? )

Comment: now i am reading,i am sorry

Comment: and i am appreciate that you can solve my question,thanks a lot!